# What is the possible relevance of $R$-parity to dark matter?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, supersymmetry, dark-matter

So say if [$R$-parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-parity) is preserved, then whatever particle (if we assume its a particle) the dark matter consists of, only interacting with the weak nuclear force and gravitational, then wouldn't this particle decay?  I'm not sure I understand what $R$-parity is.

Comment: maybe you should start with this  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-parity

Comment: Thanks, anna but what I don't understand is how does a particle with r-parity prevent it from decay?

Comment: It depends on conservation of R parity, that is the model where  the lowest mass R particle cannot decay because it would violate the conservation rule. Its all in the rules/assumtions of the models

Answer (score 1):

Let's invent some new quantum number, call it, ah, whatever, why not R-parity. Now let's postulate that this quantum number is a conserved property in reactions. Further, let's assign our known particles a "0" in this quantum number, and any dark matter or other beyond-the-standard-model-particle a "1". In that case you have guaranteed that your new beyond-the-standard-model-particles can never decay into known particles, since that reaction would violate the postulated conservation of your quantum number.

In particular this means that the lightest particle of your family of new particles has to be stable. A heavier new particle (quantum number "1") can decay into a lighter new particle (quantum number also "1"). But the lightest new particle can't decay further, e.g. into neutrinos or whatever standard model particle, since those don't carry your new quantum number.

Note that pair creation or annihilation of your new particles is still allowed, so you can still search for them using a collider or some astrophysical observation.