# Question on the life-time of a super-symmetric particle

Tags: supersymmetry, half-life, supersymmetric-particles

I was watching a random video on SUSY.  In the video, they were discussing that SUSY explains dark matter.  That DM is probably a SUSY particle.

How is this possible?  We know that the life of a Top Quark is so short because of its mass.  How could any particle, SUSY or not, anywhere near that mass or larger, have a longer life before it decays?  How would DM exist in the long term if it is a more massive particle?  Or is there something special about SUSY particles, that they all can ignore the Weak Force?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the possible relevance of $R$-parity to dark matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/544670/)

Comment: See the linked answer. It is assumed that there is a conserved quantity called *R parity* that is different for supersymmetric and non-supersymmetric particles. Then the lightest supersymmetric particle cannot decay as the only lighter particles are non-supersymmetric and therefore the decay would violate conservation of R parity.